# Display Multiple selected rows from gridview to mutiple textboxes in c#

Tags: c#, datagridview, textbox, rows

I want to get data from Datagridview to text boxes but i want every row i select should be show in multiple text boxes? I am doing it but it is only select one row and show in one text box but i want to get data of multiple rows to multiple Textboxes.

```
private void dataGridView_1CellMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e) {
    // to set oem no to textfield particular.
    dataGridView1.Refresh();
    try {
        int i;
        i = dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex;
        Particular1Txt.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Celles["OEM_No"].Value.ToString();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        MessageBox.Show(es.Message);
    }    
}
```

Comment: Rather than a screenshot (you put it wrongly), could you copy-paste some relevant code instead? It would help more.

Comment: edit this and put the actual code in the post. I don't want to type all that up

Comment: Please paste the code instead of screenshotting it.

Comment: Add more explanations, for example user select multiple rows with different `RowIndex`es  or each of these textboxes is corresponding to one row or ...

Comment: If you have dynamic amount of textboxes, then maybe  better solution will be to display values of selected rows in another datagridview, where you can make cells look like separated textboxes for example

Answer (score 0):

Well, this should work (not tested thoroughly):

VB:

```
    Dim TBlist As List(Of TextBox)
    TBlist.Add(Me.TextBox1)
    TBlist.Add(Me.TextBox2)
    TBlist.Add(Me.TextBox3)
    TBlist.Add(Me.TextBox4)
    TBlist.Add(Me.TextBox5)

    Dim mLimit As Int16 = Math.Min(Me.dgv.SelectedRows.Count - 1, TBlist.Count - 1)

    For ir = 0 To mLimit
        Dim tb As TextBox = DirectCast(TBlist.Item(ir), TextBox)
        tb.Text = Me.dgv.SelectedRows(ir).cells("RequiredCellName").value
    Next
```

Converted C#:

```
    List<TextBox> TBlist = default(List<TextBox>);
    TBlist.Add(this.TextBox1);
    TBlist.Add(this.TextBox2);
    TBlist.Add(this.TextBox3);
    TBlist.Add(this.TextBox4);
    TBlist.Add(this.TextBox5);

    Int16 mLimit = Math.Min(this.dgv.SelectedRows.Count - 1, TBlist.Count - 1);

    for (ir = 0; ir <= mLimit; ir++) {
        TextBox tb = (TextBox)TBlist.Item(ir);
        tb.Text = this.dgv.SelectedRows(ir).cells("RequiredCellName").value;
    }
```

It will use as many textboxes as inserted to the list of textboxes, or as many rows as selected, which ever is less.