# DataGridView In C# to select data and show it to one textbox

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am working on a windows form application, I have made datagridview for showing my data but I also want to select some specific columns from Datagridview and show them to only one TextBox.

I have tried but it is only getting last Column named "SEIKEN_NO" to textbox but I want multiple column values to show in One TextBox.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {
        // to set oem no, fic_no and seiken_no to textbox named particular1Txt.

        dataGridView1.Refresh();

        try
        {
            if (RB1.Checked == true)
            {
                int i;
                i = dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex;

                Particular1Txt.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["FIC_No"].Value.ToString();
                Particular1Txt.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["OEM_No"].Value.ToString();
                Particular1Txt.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Seiken_NO"].Value.ToString();
            }
            else if (RB2.Checked == true)
            {
                int i;
                i = dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex;
                Particular2Txt.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["FIC_No"].Value.ToString();
                Particular2Txt.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["OEM_No"].Value.ToString();
                Particular2Txt.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Seiken_NO"].Value.ToString();
            }
```

Comment: A `TextBox` is usually supposed to show a single field. But if for any reason you want to show multiple field in it, just join strings with a separator like `,` and show the result in `TextBox`.

Comment: It looks like you've asked [a very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46539704/472495) a couple of weeks ago, but oddly you do not seem to have replied to the person who helped you. You'll be more likely to get assistance here if it is noticed that you make an effort to respond to people who come to your aid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fore each line you assign data to the TextBox:

`Particular1Txt.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["FIC_No"].Value.ToString();`

change to:

`Particular1Txt.Text += dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["FIC_No"].Value.ToString();`

note the `+=`

otherwise you are overwriting the content of the TextBox

For values concatenation formatting, you can:

`+= " " + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["FIC_No"].Value.ToString(); // very basic way to do it`

Another way example with String.Format()

```
Particular1Txt.Text=String.Format({0} {1} {2}), dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["FIC_No"].Value.ToString(),dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["OEM_No"].Value.ToString(),dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Seiken_No"].Value.ToString();
```

You can also use: String.Join() with an string array, or the StringBuilder class,

hope this help you

Comment: Thank you so much it is working, but what to do for making space in between every column value in textbox? can u tell plz?

Comment: if this solved you problem, mark the answer as correct one, than you

Answer (score 1):

```
private void dataGridView1_CellMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
    // to set oem no, fic_no and seiken_no to textbox named particular1Txt.
    dataGridView1.Refresh();
    try
    {
        if (RB1.Checked == true)
        {
            int i;
            i = dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex;
            Particular1Txt.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["FIC_No"].Value.ToString()+" "+ dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["OEM_No"].Value.ToString()+" "+dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Seiken_NO"].Value.ToString();
        }
        else if (RB2.Checked == true)
        {
            int i;
            i = dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex;
            Particular1Txt.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["FIC_No"].Value.ToString()+" "+ dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["OEM_No"].Value.ToString()+" "+dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Seiken_NO"].Value.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```